# Can't install Ubuntu anymore, no caching found

Tags: boot

Lately, I was playing with Ubuntu distributions and wanted to try another version. I was trying to make an bootable USB on Ubuntu 16.04 and got some errors that `/boot/uefi` is out of space. I searched how to clean it, but I think I deleted more than I should have done. I managed to make a bootable USB with Mac OS X, but when I tried to reboot from USB, I  got this.

```
[    1.070715] nouveau 0000:01:C0.0: priv: HUBO: 10ecc0 ffffffff (1C40822c)
[    3.378413] sid 3:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[    3.378453] sid 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument
 Can not Mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper//filesystem.squashfs on //filesystem.squashfs
```

Now I'm stuck without any functioning OS again.

I also made a hash sum check to make sure I got the right file. If there's a way to make a cache folder or something like this, I'll try it out.

Comment: The caching mode isn't your problem. Your error is obliterated by the flash from your camera. Please [edit] your post to provide the information about the mount failure

Comment: @Elder Geek, can You read it now? I'm on mobile, will try to get the text when I get on a functionally os..

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question what you should do is recreate the bootable USB. You don't mention how you created it but it sounds like you may have done something undesirable to it when you "deleted more than I should have"

I would recommend using `dd` for this task rather than 3rd party software as it's always been more reliable for me.

WARNING: Make absolutely certain you are choosing the correct device for output as there are no training wheels with `dd`

The command line should look something like `dd if=input.iso of=targetdevice`

for more detail see `man dd` or the link under source:

Source:

http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/

Comment: This, this helped me 'break' the USB on linux. I'm not sure If I wanna go again with it, but this also might Be the only good option..Do You say that USB generated that error, I was afraid it could Be from bios or some like that

Comment: The error appears to be related to an attempt to mount the live filesystem on the loop device. Mounting the live filesystem on the loop device is a normal part of the process when booting from live (installation media).  I can only assume that /dev/sdc is your live media USB flash drive based on what information you have provided. If you have more details, you can [edit] them into the question, but you won't be getting those without a functioning OS, so recreating the live media and booting into a live session is your first step.

Comment: How can I do it? Making bootable usb/dvd won't resolve my problems anymore...

Comment: That step is not optional. What led you to believe  that having a working live media to boot off of won't resolve your problem?

Comment: I'm looking to have a live media, I made 2 bootable sticks 5 times with mac os, ubuntu and other distro, I also made a stick with ubuntu on windows, still got the same error. I remember I was on working ubuntu and wanted to make a bootable usb with other ubunto version, but unetbootin told me that /boot/efi or something like that was out of space and I searched how to clean it. I got a program, cleaned some files and when I tryed to reboot ubuntu it gave me error. Now I have broken ubuntu on SSD, but not working. USB not working as well, DVD can't be read..story of my life

Comment: You have my apologies but simply repeating the information in your question does not change my understanding of your situation. "or something like that" isn't helpful nor is the term "broken" or the phrase "not working" I understand that you are frustrated, and I also understand that "(initramfs) mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed". Based on what you are telling me you have repeatedly tried to make a bootable USB, had some problem (not fully identified) with Unetbootin, got some unidentified program "cleaned some files" and got the error mentioned. I can read by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a bad superblock. To fix this:

Firstly, boot into a live CD or USB

Find out your partition number by using

```
 sudo fdisk -l|grep Linux|grep -Ev 'swap'
```

Then, list all superblocks by using the command:

```
 sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda2 | grep superblock
```

Replace sda2 to your drive number

You should get a similar output like this

```
 Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-6 Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32774 Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98310 Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163846 Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229382 Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294918 Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819206 Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884742 Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605638 Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654214 Backup superblock at 4096000, Group descriptors at 4096001-4096006 Backup superblock at 7962624, Group descriptors at 7962625-7962630 Backup superblock at 11239424, Group descriptors at 11239425-11239430 Backup superblock at 20480000, Group descriptors at 20480001-20480006 Backup superblock at 23887872, Group descriptors at 23887873-23887878
```

Choose an alternate superblock from this list, for this case alternate superblock # 32768

Now, to check and repair a Linux file system using alternate superblock # 32768:

```
 sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda2 -y
```

The -y flag is used to skip all the Fix? questions and to answer them all with a yes automatically

You should get similar output like this:

```
 fsck 1.40.2 (12-Jul-2007) e2fsck 1.40.2 (12-Jul-2007) /dev/sda2 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced. Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes Pass 2: Checking directory structure Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity Pass 4: Checking reference counts Pass 5: Checking group summary information Free blocks count wrong for group #241 (32254, counted=32253). Fix? yes Free blocks count wrong for group #362 (32254, counted=32248). Fix? yes Free blocks count wrong for group #368 (32254, counted=27774). Fix? yes .......... /dev/sda2: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED ***** /dev/sda2: 59586/30539776 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 3604682/61059048 blocks
```

Now try mounting the partition

```
 sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Now, try to browse the filesystem with the following commands

```
  cd /mnt mkdir test ls -l cp file /path/to/safe/location
```

If you are able to perform the above commands, you have most probably fixed your error.

Now, restart you computer and you should be able to boot normally.

Source:http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/

Comment: Ty for your help, but unfortunantely it doesn't find  the `fdisk` command. Also I do believe that I need  a folder to stock caches, but is missing!

Comment: Try installing fdisk and then do it again

Comment: Oh sry correction u cant do it even :(